# How do I pass a reference of an object greater than 1MB to another activity in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bitmap

I'm trying to just keep a Bitmap in memory for the next activity to use without putting it in the extras bundle due to its size or saving it to the sd card for performance issues.  Is there any way to pass a reference to my Bitmap to another activity.

I want to do something like this

```
Bitmap myBitmap = null;
Intent newIntent = new Intent(thisClass.this, nextActivity.class);
newIntent.putExtra("bitmap", reference to myBitmap);
```

If I pass the full bitmap it crashes because the file is over 1MB in size, so I just want to pass a reference or possibly contain the file in another class and serialize it or something I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Why not pass the path of the bitmap and not the bitmap itself? Ain't that much easier.

Answer (score 0):

## You can put the bitmap in the Application Context.

The "Intent" will not pass the reference, but to serialize and deserialize the bitmap object.